# Платформа lsFusion. Ошибка сервера. Сервис падает

Tags: lsfusion

У меня аналогичная проблема. Установил решение MyCompany на Windows 10 по этой ссылке: Документация и получил краш сервера. В логе вижу это:

11 июл. 2023 19:55:05,663 INFO StartLogger - Server is starting... 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:06,946 INFO StartLogger - Logics instance is starting... 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:06,995 INFO StartLogger - Initializing BusinessLogics 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:07,020 INFO StartLogger - Creating modules 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:07,022 INFO StartLogger - Initializing localizer 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:07,021 INFO StartLogger - Initializing string literals data 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:07,994 INFO StartLogger - Initializing dependencies 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:08,288 INFO StartLogger - Initializing modules order 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:08,301 ERROR StartLogger - Exception while starting logics instance: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in module 'Individual': required module 'Icon' was not found. at lsfusion.server.physics.dev.module.ModuleList.getRequiredModuleWithCheck(ModuleList.java:100) at lsfusion.server.physics.dev.module.ModuleList.filterWithTopModule(ModuleList.java:71) at lsfusion.server.logics.BusinessLogics.initModuleOrders(BusinessLogics.java:383) at lsfusion.server.physics.dev.module.controller.init.InitModuleOrderTask.run(InitModuleOrderTask.java:13) at lsfusion.server.base.task.Task.proceed(Task.java:154) at lsfusion.server.base.task.Task$1.aspectRun(Task.java:112) at lsfusion.server.base.controller.thread.ExecutorFactory$AspectRunnable.run(ExecutorFactory.java:475) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) at lsfusion.server.base.controller.thread.ExecutorFactory$ClosableDaemonThreadFactory$ClosableThread.run(ExecutorFactory.java:554) 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:08,309 INFO StartLogger - Error starting server, server will be stopped. 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:08,310 INFO StartLogger - Server is stopping... 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:08,310 INFO StartLogger - Logics instance is stopping... 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:08,310 INFO StartLogger - Logics instance has stopped... 
11 июл. 2023 19:55:08,312 INFO StartLogger - Server has stopped...

В какую сторону смотреть? Как исправить?
Если указал мало исходных данных прошу уточнить какие именно нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, что указали на проблему. По ошибке произошла сборка из неправильной версии исходников. Пересобрали файл [mycompany-1.0.jar](https://download.lsfusion.org/solutions/mycompany-1.0.jar) - попробуйте ещё раз скачать его и поместить в серверную директорию согласно инструкции в документации.

Comment: Добрый вечер! Это не помогло. Падает с такими же ошибками в логе.

Comment: Каким образом мне Вам отправить логи, чтобы было проще понять где ошибка?

Comment: Контакты внизу страницы https://lsfusion.org
Лучше всего Slack или Telegram